# We have a tree T on n vertices. Prove that the centre of the tree T is isomorphic to a complete graph on 2 vertices if and only if diam(T)=2*rad(T)-1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I know that the tree $T$ has $n-1$ edges, one component (it is connected), and does not contain a cycle (that is, from each vertex to each there is a single path, or between every two vertices of the tree there is a single path, otherwise there would be a cycle) and we want to show the equivalence between the statements: The center of the tree $T$ is isomorphic to $K_2$ (a complete graph on 2 vertices) and $diam(T) = 2\;rad(T)-1$ holds, so we have to prove implications in both directions:
The first implication: If the center of the tree $T$ is isomorphic with $K_2$ (a complete graph on 2 vertices), then $diam(T) = 2\;rad(T)-1$ holds. Well, we know from the assumption that the Centre of the tree $T$ (that is, the induced subgraph of the tree T) is induced only on two vertices, let's denote them $x$, $y$, which are with eccentricity $ ecc(x)=ecc(y)=rad(T)$ and the other vertices necessarily have an eccentricity greater than $rad(G)$, we also know that for every connected graph: $rad(G)\leq diam(G)\leq 2\;rad(G)$, and if we want to show that $diam(T)= 2\;rad(T)-1$, so that $rad(T)=(diam(T)+1)/2$. But if we use the fact that in every tree there is a single path between any two vertices and its length is at most as much as the number of edges in the tree, i.e. $n-1$, which is basically also the maximum possible eccentricity that we can achieve in any tree, therefore, in addition to the fact that $diam(T)\leq 2\;rad(T)$, $diam(T)\leq n-1$ also holds, after adding the inequalities we have $2\;diam(G)\leq 2\;rad(T)+ n-1$ and after dividing by two we have $diam(T)\leq rad(T)+(n-1)/2$, so $rad(T)\geq diam(T)-(n-1)/2$, but how would I show the equality, and how would I prove the opposite implication? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show that the path achieving the diameter must contain all the vertices of the center. The conclusion (in both ways) follows easily from this fact.

Comment: My proof of this statement, that the path achieving the diameter must contain all the central vertices would be: Let T be a tree. Let (v0, v1, ..., vk) be path of length of the diameter, so it is the longest of the shortest paths in a graph, and there exists exactly one path between any two vertices, so there is no longer path.

Comment: We must show that there is no vertex in T with eccentricity less than that of the centers of the path, i.e. that the centers of the path are the centers of T. To show this,
note that any vertex not on the path (v0, v1, ..., vk) is a greater distance from
the ends of the path than the nearest vertex to it that lies on the path, since
the path between any two vertices of T is unique. Therefore, for any vertex
u /∈ {v0, v1, ..., vk} there exists vi ∈ {v0, v1, ..., vk} such that eccentricity(u) >
eccentricity(vi). So, the vertices of T, which are the centers of T, lie on the path we defined.

Comment: But how from this fact I can see, that there is equivalence: The tree has its centre isomorphic to complete graph on  vertices if and only if its diameter = 2 * radius - 1?

Comment: You have everything needed to conclude. You now know that the center of the tree is given by the center of the path.  Depending on the parity of the diameter, how many vertices achieve the maximum eccentricity?

Comment: Well, if you mean path only, then always two vertices achieve the maximum eccentricity (diameter) for both even or odd diameter, but if you mean the tree, I do not know, there can be any number, or? But we have proven, that all central vertices must be on the path of length equal to diameter of the tree (also of this path) and if the diameter is equal to $2*radius-1$, so it is odd, so the number of vertices on this path is even (because every tree/path with n vertices has n-1 edges) and we always remove 2 leaves until exactly two central vertices are left (so the centre is isomorphic to $K_2$.

Comment: But how to show that from the fact that the centre is isomorphic to the complete graph on two vertices then (surely the diameter is odd) but why it is exactly $diameter=2*radius-1$? By mathematical induction? So we want to prove that for every even amount of vertices (of the path) the diameter is equal to 2 * radius - 1, for number of vertices equal to k=2, the diameter is 1 and also radius is 1, so 1=2 * 1 - 1 which is true, for k=4: diameter = 3, and radius = 2, so 3=2 * 2 -1 = 3, and if we pressume that for k=2m, where m is some natural number (k is even) the equality holds, then for k+2

Comment: The radius is the eccentricity of vertices at the centre of the path. We immediately see that these vertices have eccentricity 2diameter -1

Comment: then also for k+2 it is true: If we have k+2 vertices on the path (and surely we know that every tree/path has at least two leaf vertices) then if we remove two leaves, we will get path with k vertices, so we can use the inductive hypothesis (that for even k the diameter = 2 * radius -1) and if we add the leaves back, then also we added two edges, so the diameter will increas by 2, and radius will increase by 1 (on bath sides of the central vertex) so we get the equation: $diameter+2 = 2*(radius+1)-1$.

Comment: There really is no need for induction, and your induction makes no sense since removing extremities of a diameter path does not necessarily decrease he diameter (And sorry, I meant diameter=2radius-1)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, because that would be true only for given path, not full tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will turn our exchange into an answer.

Let $d$ be the diameter and $r$ be the radius. Let $p$ be a shortest path of length $d$.

Clearly, vertices on the center of the path have eccentricity $\lceil \frac{d}{2}\rceil$, because if there exists a vertex further, then redirecting $p$ in this direction would increase the diameter, which is a contradiction.

Let's show that any vertex of minimal eccentricity belongs to $p$. Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be the paths linking this vertex to the two extremities of $p$. These two paths cover $p$, so at least one is strictly longer than $\frac{d}{2}\rceil$, hence it can't be a vertex of minimum eccentricity.

We conclude that the center of the graph is the same as the center of the path $p$, which is made of one vertex if $p$ has an even length and two vertices if $p$ has an odd length. In the latter case, we have $d = 2r-1$.